# What is a pro-tem moderator meaning?

Tags: discussion, badges, moderators

Recently there are two new gold badges added in meta site.

- **Sheriff** : Served as an elected moderator for at least 1 year
- **Constable** : Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

I understood the requirement of Sheriff badges that it can be awarded once a user get elected in election as Moderator and does service for at least 1 year.

The definition of  Constable badge says "Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation", here what is the meaning of pro-tem moderator ?

Comment: The specific blog about this: [Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

Comment: @animuson, thanks, and when you become modeartor ?

Comment: Both badges are not added only on meta site but on every sites.